# how to get the message in NSLocalizedDescription in iOS?

Tags: ios7, nserror

I have this error in requesting data from api.. All I want is to get only the message "The request timed out." in `NSLocalizedDescription`. How to get that? heres the return error below.

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
>   UserInfo=0xa5bd490 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=api url,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=api url, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed
>   out., NSUnderlyingError=0xa5763b0 "The request timed out."}

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I solved already this problem issue...

```
NSString *getError = error.localizedDescription;
```